# AngularJS - применение стилей к 1элементу из списка

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, style

Начал изучать 1-ый Angular. И, как полагается, пробую сделать свой ToDo-List. Есть контейнер с задачами, соответственно. Выглядит след. образом

```html
<div class="ui divided items">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="task in vm.tasks" ng-class="{'complete-task': task.status == true}" ng-style="vm.thisTask">
    <div class="task-description"></div>
    <div class="ui menu">
      <button class="item ui button btn-menu" ng-click="vm.taskMenu(task)">
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="menu task-menu" ng-show="vm.menu == task" style="position: absolute; left: 60px;">
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="task-color" ng-click="vm.thisTask = {'background-color': 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 0.16)'}">
        <label for="1"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="task-color" ng-click="vm.thisTask = {'background-color': '#F44336'}">
        <label for="2"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="3" name="task-color" ng-click="vm.thisTask = {'background-color': '#FF9100'}">
        <label for="3"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="4" name="task-color" ng-click="vm.thisTask = {'background-color': '#FFEB3B'}">
        <label for="4"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="5" name="task-color" ng-click="vm.thisTask = {'background-color': '#78CB5B'}">
        <label for="5"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="6" name="task-color" ng-click="vm.thisTask = {'background-color': '#80A6CD'}">
        <label for="6"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Смена цвета происходит через ng-click на label.
Вопрос: Как поменять фон только одного элемента в списке?
Пока только получается менять цвет всех задач в списке сразу.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input ng-style="{ 'background-color' : (task.status === true) ? '#F44336' : 'black' }">
```